# OData path template is not a valid OData path template

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I have a HttpGet method that has the ODataRoute

```
["Users({userId}/Tags)"]
```

`userId` is a string and the method name is `UserTags`. Controller is `UsersController`.

When I run the app I get the following error:

> The path template `Users({userId})/Tags` on the action 'UserTags' in
>   controller `Users` is not a valid OData path template. Found an
>   unresolved path segment `Tags` in the OData path template
>   `Users({userId})/Tags`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The constraints for `ODataRoute` are pretty strict, your user entity must have a collection property called 'Tags' for your route to work.

With the following code I got it to work without errors:

```
public class UserController : ODataController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [System.Web.OData.Routing.ODataRoute("User({userId})/Tags")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetTags([FromODataUri]int userId)
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Holy crap. Thanks! This took me several days for a problem that shouldn't have been. Thanks so much!

Comment: is this possible to override this beahaviour?

Comment: @zolty13, not that I know. This answer is a bit old, you could try the new OData version for Asp.NET Core >2.0 maybe.